# Talking about age

Tags: phrase-usage, adjectives

Are they correct?

> 1. I'm twenty years old.
> 2. I'm a 20-year-old student.

I wonder why the *year* has to add *-s* in the first sentence (I'm twenty years old).

What is the function of *years*? Noun? Adjective?

Could you please help and explain it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are **both** correct.

**I am a twenty-year-old student:**

> 1. "**20**" and "**year**" are linked by the hyphen to create a single term ("**20-year**") that modifies "**old**."
> 2. "***20-year***" and "***old***" are linked by the hyphen to create a single term ("***20-year-old***") that modifies "***student***."

**I am twenty years old:**

> 1. "**old**" is a **predicate adjective** for "**I**." (as in "I am old.") As a single-word adjective for "**I**," it is not joined with a hyphen to the previous adjective, "**years**."
> 2. "***years***" modifies "***old***," and "***20***" modifies "***year***". "***20***" and "***years***" are not acting as a single adjective for "***old***," so they, too, do not need a hyphen.

---

***The easy understanding:***

If the adjective phrase serves as a single modifier ***before*** the noun (*student*, in the second sentence), it needs a hyphen (or hyphens, as in this case). Adjective phrases **have no plural forms** on the words forming them (the word *year* you asked). When you use a noun as an adjective (*year-old*), it ***must*** be singular. That's why there is no **-s** there.

If it is ***after*** the noun, it doesn't need a hyphen (or hyphens). When the same words (*years*) are used **not** as an **single** adjective, which means they modify the noun **separately**, the noun is plural. That's why there is an **-s** there (unless it's *She is 1 year old*).

Another example:

> - The ceiling is ten feet high.
> - The room has a ten-foot ceiling.

Comment: Thanks a lot Safira. However, I wondering that twenty years is noun phrase so it can be plural. But I still don't understand it well.

Comment: I've modified the answer for you. Take a look.