# "He is aged 45" and "He is 45 years old"

Tags: meaning, difference, usage

- He is aged 45
- He is 45 years old

Do both expressions have the same meaning and can used interchangeably?

Comment: They are mostly interchangeable, yes. However, *"He is aged 45"* is typically only encountered in medical text, or when talking about someone who's dead.

Comment: Related questions I want to link to this one: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/11968/ https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/75993/ https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/3234/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These both have the same meaning and can be used interchangeably. However the second of the two is much more common.

"He is aged 45" means that the person or people you are referring to is/are of the given age. Note that this is exclusive of a person. "~ years old" can apply to a non-person object such as a building too.

Answer (score 1):

“He is 45 years old” is better. It is more commonly used.

One way "He is aged 45" could be improved is "His age is 45". That sounds more medical and distant though than "He is 45 years old". It depends on the setting.

Answer (score 0):

**aged** - *not used before a noun* : having reached a specified age ♦ a woman aged 40 [=a woman who is 40 years old] ♦ a child aged 10 ♦ a group of men aged between 20 and 30.

So, it appears that *"He is aged 45"* is not a very felicitous wording.

Comment: When you quote a source, you must provide a link to that source (or provide a citation if it's not online), use quote syntax to mark it visually as a quote, and tell us where the quote comes from.  Otherwise, you are plagiarizing the source, which is not allowed.  Please see: [**How to reference material written by others**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)